# How to make Laravel read an exiting column?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. I am new with Laravel and I don't know how to fix the problem which occurs after trying to run the command PHP artisan DB: seed

The mistake that it gives me is:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in
>   'field list' (SQL: insert into `roles` (`name`) values (admin))
>
> Connection.php:458
>         PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'")

I have this code into Role.php file:

```
<?PHP

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
    public $timestamps = false; }
```

and into User.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail; use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable; use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

...

public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    } }
```

and UserTableSeeder file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder; use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; use App\User; use App\Role;

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        User::truncate();
        DB::table('role_user')->truncate();

        $adminRole = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
        $authorRole = Role::where('name', 'author')->first();
        $userRole = Role::where('name', 'user')->first();

        $admin = User::create([
            'name' => 'Admin User',
            'email' => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password')
        ]);

        $author = User::create([
            'name' => 'Admin User',
            'email' => 'author@author.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password')
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => 'User User',
            'email' => 'user@user.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password')
        ]);

        $admin->roles()->attach($adminRole);
        $author->roles()->attach($authorRole);
        $user->roles()->attach($userRole);

    }
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which roles package you use? Laravel does not have natively roles managment

Comment: Share your migrations to get better solutions

Comment: isn't this import necessary?  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; in UserTableSeeder.php

Comment: As far as one can tell from what you've shared, you're lacking a `name` column in your roles table. Plus, somewhere you've not shown you're trying to insert a new role with the name `admin`. You might want to take a look into your migrations and table structures.

Comment: Agree with @D.Petrov. Also, could it be possible that you accidentally added line `protected $table = roles` in your User Model?'

Comment: @Giacomo M  I used nothing more than an AUTH and UI , and I added new controllers but nothing more.

Comment: I checked the name columns in the role tables, I have the new role with the admin and everything was fine. I checked it about 20 times and I asked a friend to checked it again because when it's my code it's normal to not see my mistake but my friend didn't found anything wrong. Migrations were also fine. But, as I am running out of time with a project, I copied the parts that were working and make a new project.

Thank you all for your quick responses.

Comment: @Viktoria_PD the error is pretty clear: the table roles does not have "name" column. Check the database and that table